# Mathematica 10.1 availability

Tags: version-10

According to [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/468436) post and [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn101.html) page of the *Wolfram Documentation Center* a new *Mathematica* version is on the way, if not already available to some user.

It'll be v. 10.1 and, as such, a rather major upgrade after Mathematica 10.0.1 and 10.0.2.

Does anyone have it already?

Comment: It's on its way "soon" but that doesn't qualify how soon. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20766670#20766670. Could be next week, could be in two weeks, who knows.

Comment: While interesting, this question will have nil value after version 10.1 is released

Comment: Completely agree w belisarius and also only WRI could answer - and if they chose to wouldn't they make it public? Close?

Comment: Sorry but I was just wandering if the new version was already available to someone or not. I got the answer (not yet)

Comment: FWIW this is a fine discussion to have, but is better suited for chat.

Comment: I Agree. I just discovered the chat rooms existence after reading blochwave comment

Comment: @LucaM Beta testers of Mathematica are usually asked not to reveal any information about it.  So even if someone has a beta version, they won't be allowed to talk about it.  No, I do not have 10.1.  The feature list looks nice, quite a few useful additions.

Comment: @Szabolcs 2 I know. My question was also due to the fact that I just have a Mathematica Home Edition with Premier Service expired. I don't know if I'll be eligible for the upgrade to 10.1 (but I was for 10.0.2 even after Premier Service expiration)

Comment: @LucaM I got a download link for 10.1 yesterday.

Comment: @GordonCoale I chatted with the customer support today and they told me its free only for those who upgraded 15 February or later